# Non-standard names used for main chatrooms of a site across the networks?

Tags: support, chat, fun

For inspiration, amusement, and reference, I am interested in a list of all chatrooms that:

- are the official/main chat room of some Stack Exchange site;
- have a non-standard name, i.e., something other that is not derived from the site’s name in a straightforward manner like *Lepitopterology SE General Chat.*

Feel free to offer explanations if the pun or similar is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 27):

Please feel free to join and contribute to any of these chatrooms (and others you may find on any of the sites here).

To find chat, just hit on the hamburger and select 'chat' (note that you'll need 20 reputation points to participate in chat).

> [image]

**Chat room names**, sorted alphabetically by *site* name:

| Parent Site | Chat room name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No parent site | The Assembly | generic public room for moderation issues |
| No parent site | The Terminal | generic room for international sites |
| 3D Printing | The Hotbed - 3D Printing | frozen |
| Academia | The Ivory Tower |  |
| Amateur Radio | Ham Shack |  |
| Anime & Manga | Maid Café (メイド喫茶) |  |
| Arduino | Pin 13 |  |
| Arqade | The Bridge |  |
| Artificial Intelligence | The Singularity |  |
| Arts & Crafts | The Studio |  |
| Astronomy | The Observatory |  |
| Aviation | The Hangar |  |
| Beer, Wine & Spirits | The Taphouse |  |
| Biblical Hermeneutics | The Library | frozen |
| Bicycles | The Velodrome |  |
| Biology | The Biosphere |  |
| Blender | The Renderfarm |  |
| Chemistry | The Periodic Table |  |
| Christianity | The Upper Room |  |
| Code Golf | The Nineteenth Byte | In golf, "the nineteenth hole" would refer to a restaraunt at the end of the course. "The Nineteenth *Byte*" flips this around to be about *code-golfing* instead of regular golf, and just so also happens to be exactly nineteen characters long. |
| Code Review | The 2nd Monitor |  |
| Coffee | The Percolator |  |
| Community Building | The Town Hall |  |
| Computer Graphics | The Cornell Box |  |
| Computer Science Educators | The Classroom |  |
| Cross Validated | Ten fold |  |
| Cryptography | The Side Channel |  |
| Database Administrators | The Heap™ – Consultancy ©® | used to be *The Clustered Index*, but that implied more organization than our chat typically reflected |
| DevOps | ChatOps | ChatOps is a way of handling infrastructure from a chat system |
| Drones and Model Aircraft | Droning On |  |
| Earth Science | What on Earth? |  |
| Ebooks | The Appendix |  |
| Emacs | *scratch* | frozen |
| Engineering | The Skunk Works |  |
| English Language Learners | Language Overflow |  |
| Ethereum | Whisper |  |
| Expatriates | The Embassy |  |
| French Language | Chez Cosette |  |
| Gardening & Landscaping | The Garden Shed |  |
| Genealogy & Family History | Roots |  |
| German Language | deutschsprachiger Raum | translates to both, *German-speaking room* and *German language area* |
| Graphic Design | The Ink Spot |  |
| Hardware Recommendations | The Rec Center |  |
| History | The Time Machine |  |
| History of Science and Mathematics | On the Shoulders of Giants |  |
| Information Security | The DMZ | [Network Demilitarised Zone](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/485) |
| Internet of Things | Chat of Things |  |
| Interpersonal Skills | The Awkward Silence |  |
| Islam | Jaami'at StackExchange al-Islamyya |  |
| Italian Language | Bar Sport | *Bar Sport* is the first novel by the Italian satirical writer Stefano Benni, which is nowadays considered a classic of Italian humorous fiction. It's an humorous description of a typical small-town Italian bar. This Bar Sport appears in other novels by Benni. |
| Language Learning | The Language Lab |  |
| Latin Language | CONLOQVIVM | '[to talk together](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-we-call-the-chatroom)' |
| Law | The Sidebar |  |
| Lifehacks | The Junk Drawer |  |
| Linguistics | lɪŋˈgwɪstɪks | *linguistics* in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) |
| Literature | The Reading Room |  |
| Martial Arts | Open Roda |  |
| Matter Modeling | Modeling Matters! |  |
| Medical Sciences | Grand Rounds |  |
| Meta Stack Exchange | Tavern on the Meta | general room for Meta.SE<sup>1</sup> |
| Meta Stack Exchange | Teachers' Lounge | private, moderator-only chat room for moderators of all network sites<sup>1</sup> |
| Mi Yodeya | V'dibarta Bam | "And speak of them" (Deuteronomy 6:7) |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair | The Pitstop |  |
| Movies & TV | The Screening Room |  |
| Music Fans | Off the record |  |
| Music: Practice & Theory | The Practice Room |  |
| Mythology & Folklore | The Pantheon |  |
| Open Source | The Bikeshed |  |
| Parenting | The Playground |  |
| Personal Finance & Money | Show me the money! |  |
| Pets | The Litter Box |  |
| Philosophy | The Symposium |  |
| Physical Fitness | The Locker Room |  |
| Physics | The h Bar | [ħ (pronounced *h bar*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant#Value) is an important physical constant |
| Politics | Agora | [agora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora) was a public open place in Ancient Greece used for assemblies, gatherings |
| Portuguese Language | Falatório |  |
| Programming Language Design & Implementation | The Garbage Collector |  |
| Psychology & Neuroscience | The Axon Terminal |  |
| Puzzling | The Sphinx's Lair |  |
| Quantitative Finance | Quant | frozen |
| Quantum Computing | The Classical Channel |  |
| Raspberry Pi | The Bakery |  |
| Retrocomputing | The BBS |  |
| Robotics | Asimov's Corner | attribution to [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), an American writer and professor who devised the [Three Laws of Robotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics) |
| Science Fiction & Fantasy | The Restaurant at the End of the Universe | [the second book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe) in the *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* by Douglas Adams, a science-fiction classic |
| Seasoned Advice | The Frying Pan |  |
| ServerFault | The Comms Room |  |
| Signal Processing | Post-Processing |  |
| Skeptics | Hub of Reason |  |
| Software Engineering | The Whiteboard |  |
| Sound Design | The Echo Chamber |  |
| Space Exploration | The Pod Bay | [2001: "Open the Pod Bay doors, Hal"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/38) |
| Spanish Language | La Tertulia | literally, 'The Salon' |
| Sports | The Clubhouse |  |
| Stellar | Lumenati |  |
| Super User | Root Access |  |
| The Great Outdoors | The Base Camp |  |
| The Workplace | The Water Cooler |  |
| Tor | The Exit Node |  |
| Travel | You Are Here |  |
| Unix & Linux | /dev/chat |  |
| Veganism & Vegetarianism | The Greenhouse |  |
| Vi and Vim | :chat! |  |
| Web Applications | Google-Fu |  |
| Woodworking | The Workshop |  |
| WordPress Development | The Loop |  |
| Worldbuilding | The Factory Floor |  |
| Writing | The Overlook Hotel |  |

<sup>1</sup> Rooms for Meta Stack Exchange above aren't hosted on the general Stack Exchange chat server (`chat.stackexchange.com`), but instead on the Meta Stack Exchange chat server (`chat.meta.stackexchange.com`).

Comment: Why no links to the chat rooms? Is there a specific reason, or just lack of time to add all of them?

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard the tavern is not on chat.se. So if it even belongs in this list at least that one should be linked to prevent confusion

Comment: @rene well, MSE is a Stack Exchange site like any other, and the room name isn't standard, so yeah I think it belongs here. As for linking it, I think it will cause confusion: why this is linked and the rest are not.

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard: What would be the benefit? This purpose of this list is not to allow people to quickly find rooms to join. On the other hand, the underlining would impede readability.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft benefit is making it much more simple to join a room you find interesting, instead of having to manually search for the site/room. :)

Comment: Would it be useful to include the mod room called the Teachers' Lounge or something?

Comment: @Chair I've included all chat rooms with funny names that have no parent site.

Comment: The one on [diy.se] should be called _Room for Improvement_.

Comment: @user289905: Well, you can probably make a suggestion on [DIY Meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/).